# Total no. of Projects assigned to a User ID

Tags: sharepoint-server, project-templates, task-assignment

Working on a Dashboard solution to showcase the Total No. of Projects which are assigned to a user ID.

Example: User1 if owner of 5 Projects, then Dashboard to show 05 Projects if USER 1 is selected.

## Background

I have created a Project based template that has

- Tasks
- SharePoint Lists
- Calendar

Currently in our testing phase, created 7 projects based on the Project template wherein User1 is the owner of all the projects. Going forward, we want to have an overall Project dashboard that gives the Project team a view of all Projects wherein the owner is User1. I`m not sure as what approach would be appropriate to get count of projects.

How it can be achieved?

Comment: Please provide proper description of your problem with your efforts, or with some code chunk so someone can get exact idea about your problem.

Comment: I have created a Project based template that has Tasks, SharePoint Lists, Calendar. Currently in our testing phase, created 7 projects based on the Project template wherein User1 is the owner of all the projects.
Going forward, we want to have an overall Project dashboard that gives the Project team a view of all Projects wherein the owner is User1. I`m not sure as what approach would be appropriate to get count of projects. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: So you can add list view webpart of the task list and can filter it on "assigned to" column using filter webpart.